# Exporting NextJS 13 project with Turbo to pure HTML / CSS with no minification and inline styles

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, next.js, turbopack

I have a project in NextJS 13 that uses Turbopack and I need to export it to pure HTML / CSS with no minification

Basically I expect the built project to look like something in the browser inspect element

I've tried setting things like compression and swcMinify to false in next js config

```
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        unoptimized: true,
    },
    compress: false,
    swcMinify: false,
}
```

But the code exported unfortunately is minified by Turbo or Next I'm not sure and has inline css styles in the html which is ugly and no good for a html template

What would be the best way to achieve this aka going from NextJS project to a plain HTML template

Documentation for NextJS 13 is scarce or hardly searchable and most of it doesn't apply to my problem aka minification and those inline styles

Comment: I guess you just can't do it yet: https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/turbopack#unsupported-features

Comment: SWC Minify only minifies the generated javascript, not the markup. Also if you use global css stylesheets, no inline styles are added into your HTML.